# React Native, runs fine while react-native run-ios, crashing when deployed via testflight

Tags: ios, react-native

So I'm a bit stuck here, my app runs fine whilst running locally via metro bundler react-native run-ios...

However when its deployed via testflight and I enter a particular screen I get a crash and the following crash report:

```
{"app_name":"myApp","app_cohort":"2|date=1540402200000&sf=143444&tid=bb84ca05a7be8e2da05f0db328a2ba46d76ab3285e3658175938c5ca87d6cd0f&ttype=i","app_version":"1.0","timestamp":"2018-10-24 18:37:52.73 +0100","slice_uuid":"2c0e8da0-b543-3014-808a-e0e35880f848","adam_id":1440030197,"build_version":"15","bundleID":"org.deliver.my.stuff.myApp","share_with_app_devs":true,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.3.1 (15E302)","incident_id":"68871235-3982-4B92-954B-E7205263E4E1","is_beta":true,"name":"myApp"}
Incident Identifier: 68871235-3982-4B92-954B-E7205263E4E1
Beta Identifier:     D6077464-5670-4488-A863-51B4947CDF37
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,3
Process:             myApp [832]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AB5305E3-6C91-48FE-89C7-CB5F6706A6DC/myApp.app/myApp
Identifier:          org.deliver.my.stuff.myApp
Version:             15 (1.0)
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           org.deliver.my.stuff.myApp [783]


Date/Time:           2018-10-24 18:37:52.6426 +0100
Launch Time:         2018-10-24 18:37:49.7676 +0100
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.3.1 (15E302)
Baseband Version:    2.03.12
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  3

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1841ded8c 0x1833985ec 0x1004fef20 0x1004fc9e0 0x1841e6580 0x1840c5748 0x1840ca56c 0x10051296c 0x100556de0 0x100556b40 0x183ad0b24 0x183ad0ae4 0x183adaa38 0x183adb380 0x183adbd4c 0x183ae411c 0x183e03e70 0x183e03b08)
```

myApp is just a name I've replaced the actual name of the app with - like I said it runs fine but I'm not quite sure how to decode this crash report?

I thought the backtrace should show the exception but it doesn't appear to?

Comment: by chance did u comment out script under`bundling react native code and images` in your build phases. I had commented that out during development phase and was facing similar issue

Comment: Hey Harkirat, hrmm, I'm not sure where would I check?

Comment: xcode, select your project... under build phases ..